# AttributeError: 'FileDataset' object has no attribute 'PixelSpacing'

Tags: python, dicom, pydicom

I want to convert the filetype of a series of images from .dcm to .mha. Following is my code:

```
import numpy
import pydicom
import os
PathDicom ='./DicomResource'
lstFilesDCM = []
for dirName, subdirList, fileList in os.walk(PathDicom):
for filename in fileList:
    if '.dcm' in filename.lower():
        lstFilesDCM.append(os.path.join(dirName, filename))

RefDs = pydicom.read_file(lstFilesDCM[0])
ConstPixelDims = (int(RefDs.Rows), int(RefDs.Columns), len(lstFilesDCM))
#RefDs.PixelSpacing = 0
ConstPixelSpacing = (float(RefDs.PixelSpacing[0]), 
float(RefDs.PixelSpacing[1]), float(RefDs.SliceThickness))
info = ConstPixelDims + ConstPixelSpacing
f = open('info.txt', 'w')
for n in info:
    f.write(str(n)+' ')
f.close()
location = []
for i in range(len(lstFilesDCM)):
    ds = pydicom.read_file(lstFilesDCM[i])
    location.append(ds.SliceLocation)
location.sort()
ArrayDicom = numpy.zeros((len(lstFilesDCM), RefDs.Rows, RefDs.Columns), 
dtype=RefDs.pixel_array.dtype)
for filenameDCM in lstFilesDCM:
    ds = pydicom.read_file(filenameDCM)
    ArrayDicom[location.index(ds.SliceLocation), :, :] = ds.pixel_array
ds = ArrayDicom.tostring()
f = open('1.mha', 'wb')
f.write(ds)
f.close()
```

With this, I am getting following error:

> AttributeError: 'FileDataset' object has no attribute 'PixelSpacing'

I also tried adding `RefDs.PixelSpacing = 0`. It throws next error. 
[image: Error]

Is there anyone can help me to solve the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Attribute "PixelSpacing" (0028,0030) is not mandatory in all SOP Classes. With some SOP Classes like "CT Image Storage" (Modality CT), this is Type "1". With many others, it is Type "1C". In SOP Classes like "Computed Radiography Image Storage" (Modality CR), equivalent attribute "Imager Pixel Spacing" (0018,1164) is included in dataset. Following quote from **2017a Part 3 - Information Object Definitions** explains this a bit.

> 10.7.1.1 Pixel Spacing
>   Pixel Spacing (0028,0030) specifies the physical distance in the patient between the center of each pixel.
>   If Pixel Spacing (0028,0030) is present and the image has not been calibrated to correct for the effect of geometric magnification, the values of this attribute shall be the same as in Imager Pixel Spacing (0018,1164) or Nominal Scanned Pixel Spacing (0018,2010), if either of those attributes are present.
>   If Pixel Spacing (0028,0030) is present and the values are different from those in Imager Pixel Spacing (0018,1164) or Nominal Scanned Pixel Spacing (0018,2010), then the image has been corrected for known or assumed geometric magnification or calibrated with respect to some object of known size at known depth within the patient.
>   If Pixel Spacing Calibration Type (0028,0A02) and Imager Pixel Spacing (0018,1164) and Nominal Scanned Pixel Spacing (0018,2010) are absent, then it cannot be determined whether or not correction or calibration have been performed.
>   Note
>   1. Imager Pixel Spacing (0018,1164) is a required attribute in DX family IODs.
>   2. Nominal Scanned Pixel Spacing (0018,2010) is a required attribute in Multi-frame SC family IODs

Looking at your question, it seems that your code is not bound to any specific Modality/SOP Class. Considering this, it is quite possible your loop encounter some instances those are missing this attribute.

**About first error:**

> AttributeError: 'FileDataset' object has no attribute 'PixelSpacing'

Error is very clear. The DICOM dataset does not contain the attribute you are looking for.

**About second error:**

> TypeError: 'DSfloat' object does not support indexing

Value Multiplicity of attribute is 2.

```
Pixel Spacing = Row Spacing\Column Spacing = 0.30 mm\0.25 mm
```

So, you should be able to access the value using index. First value should be for row and second should be column. But this depends on the implementation of your toolkit/technology. I am not aware about both here so I cannot say.

May be, your toolkit returns single value (no array; hence no index) which you should further split on separator ('\') and then use it.

Or may be that as the attribute does not present, the value of the variable is `null` (or whatever similar in your technology) and that is why indexing is not working.